# How to make links not move when icon is showing on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

Pretty much, I am trying to add an icon of a paw next to the link once its hovered. So I want icon to be invisible, and just shows when I hover over the link. I managed to do that, but when I hover over a link, other links jump to the side due to the icon being visible. How can I make it so the links already take size of the icon into consideration and do not jump on side once it shows up on hover?

```
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1CQq.png)
[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f17Ew.png)
[Before Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMFDV.png)
[After Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQv12.png)
```

Since I'm still quite new in Web Dev maybe solution to the problem is quite easy. I just tried random things which I don't even remember to be honest. Was adding and removing code just to see if it will make any difference. I didn't really manage to make any difference as no matter what I do ( try to include total width of the link after hovering to the basic width when not being hovered, and push the link text to the side blah blah ), it was always the same. Links just jump to the side when I hover.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that elements with `display:none` are not rendered in the DOM, so the width of the element will not be calculated, thats why it will move if you make them visible via `display:block`.

there are sereval solutions for your problem. I will give you two simple solutions:

**1. Use visibility**
HTML:

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon hide">icon</i>Test</a>
<a href="#"><i class="icon hide">icon</i>Test</a>
<a href="#"><i class="icon hide">icon</i>Test</a>
```

CSS:

```
.icon.hide {
  visibility:hidden
}
a:hover .icon.hide {
  visibility:visible
}
```

**2. Use opacity (here you would be able to add transition effects)**
HTML:

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon hide">icon</i>Test</a>
<a href="#"><i class="icon hide">icon</i>Test</a>
<a href="#"><i class="icon hide">icon</i>Test</a>
```

CSS:

```
.icon.hide {
  opacity:0
}
a:hover .icon.hide {
  opacity: 1
}
```

Hope this will answer your question.